# FUIEmailAuth undeclared

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am Using FIrebaseUI login for IOS but for email part I am getting undeclared error. What can be the cause?

This is my code.

```
   FUIAuth *authUI = [FUIAuth defaultAuthUI];
    authUI.delegate = self;
    NSArray<id<FUIAuthProvider>> *providers = @[
                                                [[FUIGoogleAuth alloc] init],
                                                [[FUIFacebookAuth alloc] init],
                                                [[FUIEmailAuth alloc] init],
                                                ];
    authUI.providers = providers
```

Comment: provide your trial code.

Comment: @Bhumika Singhal can you tell how did you solved this issues...I have same issues sir

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Firebase documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui#email_address_and_password), you don't need to do anything on iOS side.  You just configure it from the console of Firebase.  Once you've enabled email and password authentication, the email button will appears (see bottom if email button doesn't show up).

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
authUI?.providers = [FUIGoogleAuth.init(), FUIFacebookAuth.init()]
// To hide the email button from AuthUI:
authUI?.isSignInWithEmailHidden = true // see bottom
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
FUIAuth *authUI = [FUIAuth defaultAuthUI];
authUI.delegate = self;
NSArray<id<FUIAuthProvider>> *providers = @[
                                            [[FUIGoogleAuth alloc] init],
                                            [[FUIFacebookAuth alloc] init],
                                            ];
authUI.providers = providers;
// To hide the email button from AuthUI:
authUI.signInWithEmailHidden = YES; // see bottom
```

Note, as of FirebaseUI 6.0.0, the email button is missing.  I cannot find any documentation nor any codes to re-enable it.  `signInWithEmailHidden` property is gone.  When I set the pod version to below '6.0.0', the problem is resolve.  FirebaseUI 5.2.2 has email button.

**Podfile**

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth', '< 6.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the providers before I got a reference to the auth view controller. If I set the providers after I got the view controller reference I would not get the "sign in with email button".

```
    // get the default auth ui object
    let authui = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

    guard authui != nil else {
        // log the error
        return
    }

    // set the delegate
    authui?.delegate = self

    // 4 - define the providers
    let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
        FUIEmailAuth(),
    ]

    // set the providers
    authui!.providers = providers

    // get a referece to the auth ui view controller
    let authViewController = authui!.authViewController()

    // show it
    present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Also, I'm using FirebaseUI/Auth 6.4.3